# Visitor counter on backend - Joomla 1,5 site

Tags: joomla, visitor-statistic

Is it possible to have visitor counter that is invisible on front-end and visible on back-end of Joomla 1.5 site? I would like to know how many people is on-line on my site and see this data in the back-end.

Comment: Could you specify the joomla version you are asking for? Also I would like to know how detailed this "counter" should be and if it should only display how many people are currently online or also some stats. In my opinion there is already a display that says how many people are on the frontend and on the backend. You can find it on the top right corner in the backend.

Comment: On the back-end I can olny see how many people are logged (module Online Users) but I would like to know how many people are on my (front-end) site right now. I need information from module mod_whosonline bur on back-end only.

Comment: I do not know if this is already available in J1.5 (I have only J2.5 at hand), but if you only want to prevent "untrusted" users from seeing this stats and do not care if it is in the backend or not, then simply add the module to the frontend and set its visibility to show only to administrators.

Comment: Thanks but I don't have login module on my front-end site so I think that I should display module position using my IP address. But still I'm curious if I can get visitor counter information only back-end.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this extension on all my previous Joomla 1.5 sites. Tells you the username, IP, country, city and so on.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/analytics/visitors/8946

Hope this helps